# Bokeh equivalent of Matplotlib scatter_matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

Is there a better way of reproducing matplotlibs scatter_matrix (plot all data against all data) in Bokeh than the code below:

```
    defaults.width = 100
    defaults.height = 100
    scatter_plots = []
    y_max = len(dataset.columns)-1
    for i, y_col in enumerate(dataset):
        for j, x_col in enumerate(dataset):
            df = pd.DataFrame({x_col: dataset[x_col].tolist(), y_col: dataset[y_col].tolist()})
            p = Scatter(df, x=x_col, y=y_col)
            if j > 0:
                p.yaxis.axis_label = ""
                p.yaxis.visible = False
            if i < y_max:
                p.xaxis.axis_label = ""
                p.xaxis.visible = False
            scatter_plots.append(p)
    grid = gridplot(scatter_plots, ncols = len(dataset.columns))
    show(grid)
```

In particular I would like to be able to zoom and pan the entire grid of plots as a single entity rather than zoom/pan the subplot the mouse is hovering over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to have linked panning/zooming, you share the ranges that you want to be linked between plots. This is described here in the Users Guide:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/linking.html

You can also check out this linked SPLOM example:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/models/iris_splom.py

That example is longer/more verbose because it uses the low level `bokeh.models` API. The important part is where it re-uses the ranges `xdr` and `ydr` on ever plot that gets created.

In your particular case, since high level charts don't accept range parameters up front (IIRC), I think you'll have to fix up the charts "after the fact", so maybe something like:

```
xr = scatter_plots[0].x_range
yr = scatter_plots[0].y_range
for p in scatter_plots:
    p.x_range = xr
    p.y_range = yr
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it is useful, I faced the same problem.  In actual fact you don't want *all* the axis linked - but rather each rows y-axis linked and each columns x-axis linked.  I'm surprised that this isn't a built in bokeh feature. even iris the example gets this wrong:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/iris_splom.html

Here's a code snippet I used:

```
def scatter_matrix(dataset):
    dataset_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dataset)
    scatter_plots = []
    y_max = len(dataset.columns)-1
    for i, y_col in enumerate(dataset.columns):
        for j, x_col in enumerate(dataset.columns):
            p = figure(plot_width=100, plot_height=100, x_axis_label=x_col, y_axis_label=y_col)
            p.circle(source=dataset_source,x=x_col, y=y_col, fill_alpha=0.3, line_alpha=0.3, size=3)
            if j > 0:
                p.yaxis.axis_label = ""
                p.yaxis.visible = False
                p.y_range = linked_y_range
            else:
                linked_y_range = p.y_range
                p.plot_width=160
            if i < y_max:
                p.xaxis.axis_label = ""
                p.xaxis.visible = False
            else:
                p.plot_height=140
            if i > 0:
                p.x_range = scatter_plots[j].x_range

            scatter_plots.append(p)

    grid = gridplot(scatter_plots, ncols = len(dataset.columns))
    show(grid)
```

Comment: Well, the iris splom example is correct in the sense that it works exactly as I intended when I wrote it. It made sense to me that all the plots would be linked in the same way, so that the same area of every plot can be consistently interrogated together.  I've seen other grids that behave in the way you describe with some linked and some not, and I personally find this behavior incomprehensible and confusing. But, I'm certainly not the target audience for this kind of plot. If you'd like to update the example (with a `Div` atop that explains the interaction to viewers), I'd consider a PR

Comment: As for being built in, that would be more appropriate for a higher level tool built on top of Bokeh, e.g. [Holoviews](http://holoviews.org/)

Comment: Thanks - I think the real issue is the range of your parameters - if they all have a similar range (like iris data) then it works OK, but if your data has a varied range (e.g. plotting altitude (0 to 40,000) and mach number (range 0 to 1) and temperature (-40 to +40) having all axis shared doesn't work. So both have their place.

Comment: Fair enough, as I said definitely happy to consider a PR to update the existing example, or add a new one!